# Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in C:\Apache\htdocs\test\testSsh2_03.php on line 13

Tags: php

Running PHP 5.6.5
I have installed "libssh2.dll" under c:\PHP
I have installed "php_ssh2.dll" and "php_ssh2.pdb" in C:\PHP\ext in both flavours, 64 and 32, but none work.
I have also tried "phpseclib", and I get another error. I have researched it on the web for a couple of days now and most of the solutions are old, none have worked for me.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
   // =================================================
   // testscp_02.php
   // =================================================
   $hostname      = 'myconnection.com';
   $username      = 'my_userName';
   $password      = 'MyPassword';

   $sourceFile    = 'TestScp.php';
   $targetFile    = '/home/myDir/TestScp.php';


   $connection    = ssh2_connect($hostname, 22);
   echo '<br>[' . $connection . ']<br>';
   ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password)
   ssh2_scp_send($connection, 'C:/Apache/htdocs/test/testscp_02.php',   '/home/myDir/TestScp.php', 0666);
 ?>
```

I have tried many things, I cannot get PHP to see SSH2 as pointed out by some people that it should happens when I install the DLL as stated at the beginning of this post.

Comment: dumping some dll files onto your harddrive doesn't mean they'll be magically loaded by php. did you update your php.ini to tell php about those files and their location?

Comment: Yes, I updated my PHP.INI file, I just didn't "dump" dll files, I completed all the required steps.

Comment: well, obviously the dlls didn't get loaded, otherwise you wouldn't be getting that error. start debugging: look at php's error log and see what's happening during startup.

Comment: Just to make sure I got it right, here is the change in the PHP.INI file: extension=php_ssh2.dll and that file was copied into the "ext" directory as explained in my original post..

Comment: Do you mean the log file for Apache?

Comment: wherever your php install is doing its logging.

Comment: I am trying to look for "php_errors.log", not sure where its at. On the Apache log file there are no indications of any errors.

Comment: Is there a way I can place the php_errors.log file in a specific directory? Can I do this: error_log = c:\temp\php_errors.log

Comment: go ahead and try it. just make sure your apache userID has the rights to write in that directory.

Comment: I added it to the Apache directory "error_log = C:\Apache24\logs\php_errors.log" too make sure it writes it, but it doesn't write it.

Comment: Got it...I had uncommented error_log = syslog after the one I sent to apache, so it was being overridden...Let me see what the logs say. Thank you

Comment: Ok, here we go....[22-Sep-2015 14:39:49 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/php/ext\php_ssh2.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0 --- Any clues where I can find a valid one? I have downloaded everyone that has been suggested in various posts. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the DLLs for PHP 5.6 and it is working now.
The link is: https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=6123

I hope this helps someone else.